# Schwartzian transform in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
my @output =
map $_->[0],
sort{$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
map [$_,-s $_],     
@array;
```

Can someone explain the code in more detail? I can't get head or tail of it ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read from the bottom up:

```
@array
```

An array (of filenames, given later usage).

```
map [$_,-s $_],
```

For each filename, get a reference to a two element anonymous array, with the first element being the filename and the second element, the byte size of the file.  map returns a list of these array references.

```
sort{$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
```

Sort the list of array references by increasing file size.

```
map $_->[0],
```

Turn the list of array references back into a list of filenames, but now in sorted order.

```
my @output =
```

Save the list in @output.

This is equivalent in function to:

```
my @output = sort { -s $a <=> -s $b } @array;
```

but only gets the size for each file once instead of once per comparison done by the sort.

Comment: @compile-fan The "spaceship" operator `<=>` will compare two arguments and return 1, 0 or -1, meaning greater than, equal or lesser than.

Comment: You can look up unfamiliar operators via `perldoc perlop`. The `<=>` operator is covered under the Equality Operators section. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has a detailed [explanation and analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)