# Perl sorting a 3d array

Tags: perl, sorting, multidimensional-array

I wand to sort a 3-dimension array in Perl. The elements of the array are in the form:

$arr_3d[indA][indB][indC] , and each element for indC=1 is a number

What I need is, for a given value of indA, sort all the sub-arrays indexed/defined by indB, with the decreasing order  of the value of  $arr_3d[indA][indB][indC=1],.

e.g. for an 1x2x2 array if:

```
$arr_3d[1][1][1] = 1
$arr_3d[1][1][2] = 4
$arr_3d[1][2][1] = 2
$arr_3d[1][2][2] = 3
```

Then after sorting :

```
$arr_3d[1][1][1] = 2
$arr_3d[1][1][2] = 3
$arr_3d[1][2][1] = 1
$arr_3d[1][2][2] = 4
```

So after sorting the sub-arrays $arr_3d[1][1]  and $arr_3d[1][2] are swapped.
Sorry for the messed up description.. Any ideas?

Regards,
Giorgos

Comment: That's not a 1x2x2, that's a 2x3x3. Do you really put nothing in index zero? That's going to cause you all kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the " [Schwartzian transform in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483475/schwartzian-transform-in-perl) " . You are really just sorting a single array (`@{ $arr_3d[$indA] }`).

I test this and it works. You are probably using Fortran index notation (starting at 1), so I changed it to C indexing (starting at 0).

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr_3d ; 
$arr_3d[0][0][0] = 1; 
$arr_3d[0][1][0] = 2; 
$arr_3d[0][0][1] = 4; 
$arr_3d[0][1][1] = 3; 
my $indA = 0; 
my $indC = 0;

my @temp = @{ $arr_3d[$indA] };

@{ $arr_3d[$indA] } = sort { $b->[$indC] <=> $a->[$indC] } @temp;


print Dumper(\@arr_3d);
```

Comment: Thanks,I run the following code but gives with a "Modification of a read-only value attempted" error at the last lines:

my @arr_3d ;
$arr_3d[1][1][1] = 1;
$arr_3d[1][2][1] = 2;                       
$arr_3d[1][1][2] = 4;
$arr_3d[1][2][2] = 3;

my $indA = 1;
my $indC = 1;
@{ $arr_3d[$indA] } =
    sort { $b->[$indC] <=> $a->[$indC] }
        @{ $arr_3d[$indA] };

Comment: Try again. I fixed the example.

Comment: I have not down-voted. I tried to up-vote but my "reputation" credit was not enough as I am a new user.

Comment: @user2405602 - Someone down voted, not sure who. Sorry, I didn't mean to blame you.