# Linux Perl: How to simply arrange content of an array

Tags: linux, perl

I have read a lot of guides, maybe I just don't get it.

I have a string and converted it to an array. Now I need to arrange its content in a descending order based on the last column. Here is how my array looks like in a "string view":

```
   @array = [

   Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26

   Machine2, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 1

   Machine3, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 78

   ]
```

In this array, the whole **"Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26"** is considered a whole string in an array, and based last column (which I consider) which is: 26, 1, 78 <- I wish I could order then in a descending order: 78, 26, 1.

Sorry for the childish question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That `@array` contains only one element.

Comment: @DavidO That array isn't even a valid array. In fact, it's just a syntax error as it's currently written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal to start with an array of strings when an [array of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS) would be better, but we can work with that by [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)-ing each string into its component parts. Then we just sort on the element you're interested in, and Bob's your uncle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @array = (
    'Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26',
    'Machine2, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 1',
    'Machine3, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 78',
);

@array = sort { $b->[3] <=> $a->[3] }
         map  { [ split(/,\s*/) ] }
         @array;

dd(\@array);
```

Output:

```
[
  ["Machine3", "02/01/2016", "02/01/2016", 78],
  ["Machine1", "01/02/2016", "02/01/2016", 26],
  ["Machine2", "02/01/2016", "02/01/2016", 1],
]
```

If you need to keep the data in the original format, you can use a [Schwartzian transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483475/schwartzian-transform-in-perl):

```
@array = map  { $_->[0] }
         sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
         map  { [ $_, (split(/,\s*/))[3] ] }
         @array;
```

Result:

```
[
  "Machine3, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 78",
  "Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26",
  "Machine2, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 1",
]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! What is the dd(\@array);?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse each string, sort as desired (descending), reverse them back.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (   
    'Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26', 
    'Machine2, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 1',
    'Machine3, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 78'
);

my @sorted = map { my $s = reverse; $s }
             sort { $b cmp $a } 
             map { my $s = reverse; $s }  @array;

print "$_\n" for @sorted;
```

This prints

```
Machine3, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 78
Machine1, 01/02/2016, 02/01/2016, 26
Machine2, 02/01/2016, 02/01/2016, 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Schwartzian Transformation ( google  Schwarzian Transformation in perl )

Done by creating a new array {index,string} , sorting on index, but printing out only string ( without any further processing ).